# can't access codeigniter controller function from curl but in browser working

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I provide the API in my website so need to access the site from curl. when call the particular url from curl it can't be accessed. but in the browser it shows the result. If we put echo to check the process, upto parent construct we can get the result

```
class Apicall extends CI_Controller {
    // Constructor function 
    public function __construct()
    {   
        echo "test"; //this echo  worked
        parent::__construct();      
        echo "hfksdjhfkjsdhflksdhflkjh"; //this is not worked
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation'));
        $this->load->helper(array('url', 'language'));
    }
    public function v1()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: do you call yoursite.com/Apicall/v1? have you defined any special route for this api function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in our core controller we write the redirect function so now its working fine